# How can I determine the image path from a product

Tags: product, product-images

We have actual more and more problem with showing product images. As it shows the "default" image from Magento and no the product image.

And this everywhere on the whole page:

Here is the link: https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/fashion/

I know that I have images on the server, as I see them per ftp and in the back end. But just not showing anything in the frond end on the products.

How I can test it to see the path of a product image?

Comment: In the backend of magento have you assigned a small image/ thumbnail image to a product?

Comment: Yes, there are images...

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot of images that have been selected via the magento backend

Comment: okay, I will do prepare it. And send later a link to some images.

The issue is, yesterday evening I saw those images in the frond end... today not anymore...

Comment: Looking at the network requests there are no 404 errors for images, however there is a 404 saying it can't find swatches which could be the reason why images aren't loading. Its saying it can't find https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/skin/frontend/base/default/js/configurableswatches/swatches-product.js Failed to load resource: the server

Comment: Hi rob
This extension we not using anymore, we are working with another extension for the swatch images.

Here You see the image in the back end:

[link](https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/testimages/product_images_backend.png)

And this is the link to the product self:
[link](https://mag.outdoorequipped.com/outdoor/brands/marmot/marmot-womens-lateral-ls.html)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29997/discussion-between-rob3000-and-simon-vetterli).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved in chat:
There seems to be an issue with the js not loading the default image for the configurable image, You'll need to find out why the js isn't being loaded correctly and may need to go back to the developer that made it.